# Merge faces to use the solidify modifier and UV-map

Tags: texturing

I have some issues with welding faces together so I can use a solidify modifier properly and so I can UV-map it.

In the picture you see a cardboard folded model that is exported from a specific software. It is however loaded as seperate faces. Is there an easy and quick way to join these together? Some searching on the internet gives me nothing, maybe I use the wrong key-words...

Thanks a lot!

[image]

[image]

Comment: The illustration appears to have thickness.. is that the way it was exported?

Comment: Hi! No, those are folds of the cardboard you can see, everything is flat and has no thickness! :) If you would unfold it, it's a flat sheet.

Comment: Does M > Merge > By Distance with a tiny threshold weld the right verts together, or does it catch the wrong ones first?